# Using Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I read a couple of pages about "Membership" class and "Membership Provider" but I am not sure if I understand it. 
From all that I've read, I understand that if I want to use the "Membership" class I must initialize membership provider in web.config. This Membership class works with the "type" attribute in provider in this case with "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider". Am I right ? I need some simple and good explanation about Membership class, the name "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"(in providers in membership) and System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.

**(In this example I use the Database from file "aspnet_regsql.exe")**

Example:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="UsersConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  connectionString="Data Source=OWNER;Initial Catalog=LoginsDB;Integrated Security=True" />
```

```
  <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="UsersConnectionString"
      enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
      requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="3"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

**1.How Membership class work and know where to put information in specific fields in database ?**(For example if I use "Membership.CreateUser("admin", "admin")")

**2.Why when I change the name in "add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"" the application doesn't want to work. Is this some unique name ?**

**3.What is "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" ? Is this class works in conjuction with "Membership class"**

**4.What is this database which is generated from "aspnet_regsql.exe" file ? is it prefer   to use it when creating registration page ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.How Membership class work and know where to put information in specific fields in database ?(For example if I use "Membership.CreateUser("admin", "admin")")

The concrete class `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`, which inherits from `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider` overrides `MembershipProvider` methods and properties with implementations which target a specific database schema (namely LoginsDB's schema )

> 2.Why when I change the name in "add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"" the application doesn't want to work. Is this some unique name ?

I guess so. I must confess I never tried that. I am using CustomMemberShipProvider, and never noticed a problem with the name.

> 3.What is "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" ? Is this class works in conjuction with "Membership class"

It is an implementation of the abstract class `System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider`

> 4.What is this database which is generated from "aspnet_regsql.exe" file ? is it prefer to use it when creating registration page ?

If you use SqlMemberShipProvider, you don't really have any choice.

Depending on you framework version, you may also find give a look SimpleMemberShipProvider :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

Comment: So when I use "Membership.CreateUser("admin", "admin")", this method will use SqlMembershipProvider to put the data into database right ?

Comment: @TheChampp yes, that's it :-)